# Insert a new array item at the end of JSON array using MarkLogic Patch Builder

Tags: arrays, json, node.js, marklogic

I have a `cities.json` file in my MarkLogic database which looks like:

```
[
    { city: "New York", pop: "8.538 million (2016)"},
    { city: "Miami", pop: "453,579 (2016)"}
]
```

Using MarkLogic Patch Builder in Node.js, I would like to append one more city item to the end of the array.

```
db.documents.patch('cities.json',

    pb.insert('array-node("/")', 'last-child', { city: "Denver", pop: 682,545 (2015) })

).result();
```

However this does not seem to update `cities.json` file.

I also tried:

```
pb.insert('/array-node()', 'last-child', { city: "Denver", pop: 682,545 (2015) })

pb.insert('/array-node("/")', 'last-child', { city: "Denver", pop: 682,545 (2015) })
```

but no luck.

I've been reading this manual (https://docs.marklogic.com/guide/node-dev/partial-update#id_65749) and tried to use `array-node()` to select parent array. I notice that all the examples provided in the manual require array to have a property name. There is no example how to select array that is the parent element of the JSON.

Note that if I change my `cities.json` file to:

```
{
    "cities": [
        { city: "New York", pop: "8.538 million (2016)"},
        { city: "Miami", pop: "453,579 (2016)"}
    ]
}
```

and Patch Builder statement to:

```
pb.insert('/array-node("cities")', 'last-child', { city: "Denver", pop: 682,545 (2015) })
```

it is working as expected, however I would really prefer to keep my JSON simple as an array.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Under the hood the Node.js Client API uses the MarkLogic REST API and if you hit up its documentation you'll find a section on [limitations working with JSON documents](https://docs.marklogic.com/guide/rest-dev/documents#id_13293).

In this section it is explained that it's not possible to insert a property immediately after an "anonymous" root property. (This would be a JSON document where there's no named root property).

Your best option at the moment would be to retrieve the document, do the update in your JavaScript code and reinsert the document. This could be achieved in the following way:

```
const uri = '/cities.json';
db.documents.read(uri).result()
.then(response => {
  const document = response[0].content;
  document.push({ city: 'Denver', pop: '682,545 (2015)' });
  return db.documents.write({ uri, content: document }).result();
})
.then(response => console.info(response))
.catch(error => console.error(error));
```

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer! I thought about retrieving the document, updating and reinserting. However would this cause performance issues if document gets very large with thousand and thousand of items in the array since I need to retrieve the whole document every time I want to update it?

Comment: Have you considered modeling each city as a separate document? It's much better to have many documents and use queries to collect the documents you need into a structure dynamically instead of put a large number of records into a single document and extract the records you need.  (From a relational perspective, a MarkLogic document is a kind of super row -- flexibly hierarchical and varied -- rather than a kind of table.)

Comment: Actually my project is not about storing cities, but log events instead. I just used cities example to simplify my question of what I'm trying to do. There would be millions of log events generated monthly so having a separate document for each log event would not be good.

Comment: On the contrary, the more log events you have, the more important it is to store each log event as a separate document instead of updating a single document with all of the log events.  Use collections to group your log documents into sets.

Comment: I need to generate monthly summary reports based on the log events. I thought it would be better to store logs in monthly files (e.g. jan.json, feb.json...) instead of having them all in separate documents. Therefore when it comes to generating the report, I could just grab the month json file and filter the list based on what I need instead of querying millions of log event documents.

Comment: MarkLogic is an MVCC database.  Adding one log entry to a document with 100,000 log entries writes the entire document. MarkLogic is optimized to retrieve all of the documents in a collection or that match a query.  (The Inside MarkLogic Server white paper provides useful background:  http://www.marklogic.com/resources/inside-marklogic-server/ )

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/157019/discussion-between-ivanj-and-ehennum).